# Possible to provide custom names for mapped entity fields/properties in a Symfony form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am working with `Symfony 3.4`. Assume there is an entity `Task` with some properties, e.g. `title`, `note`, etc.

When creating a custom FormType to let the user create a new `Task` entity, each entity property is usually added using its internal name:

```
class TaskType extends AbstractMoneyControlBaseType { 
    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return 'app_task';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'The Title'
            ])        
            ->add('note', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'A Note'
            ]);

        ...
    }
}
```

This will render form fields with names like `app_task[title]` and `app_task[note]`. Is it possible to use custom names instead?

Sure, Symfony uses the identify the properties and map the input to the entity. However, it should not be to hard to specify a different name by mapping the field to a different name or vice versa by mapping a field name to the entity property.

Something like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('title', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'The Title',
        'renderedName' => 'customTitleName',
    ])        
    ->add('note', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'A Note'
        'renderedName' => 'customNoteName',
    ]);

OR

$builder
    ->add('customTitleName', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'The Title',
        'mappedFieldName' => 'title',
    ])        
    ->add('customNoteName', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'A Note'
        'mappedFieldName' => 'note',
    ]);
```

**I could not find such a solution. So, is it somehow possible to use custom field names?**

Comment: Have no idea why your post was minused. My answer was also downvoted without any description. I guess it's because of bad practice to differentiate domain model and view form. Because another developer wouldn't expect such behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is to use [property-path](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path)

```
$builder
    ->add('customTitleName', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'The Title',
        'property_path' => 'title',
        'renderedName' => 'customTitleName',
    ])        
    ->add('note', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'A Note'
        'renderedName' => 'customNoteName',
    ]);
```